# Answering your own question

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, accepted-answer

I've always wondered what the proper way to go about this is.

I posted a question on both Apple Support Communities and Ask Different. I got a response on the Support Communities first and it solved my problem.  Is it right for me to go ahead and put the solution to my problem in the Ask Different question?  For some reason I feed wrong doing it.

Comment: What is wrong about documenting your find under the creative commons license here? We're about gathering high quality answers and if you happen to ask the question too, that's not really a problem if the content itself is good.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [the FAQ:](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

> Yes! Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions. If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.

So please go ahead and fill in an answer with a solution that works. There's a grace period before your own answer becomes something you can accept but otherwise it's a-okay.

Comment: Okay, thanks!  I'm glad it's not frowned upon.